# Project the size of a set type array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am not able to display the size of an array in projection and groupby.  please find my below query.

```
[  
{  
    "$unwind":"$a"
},
{  
    $group:{  
        _id:"$a.acid",
        "sessions":{  
            $sum:1
        },
        "users":{  
            $addToSet:"$cid"
        }
    }
},
{  
    $project:{  
        "sessions":1,
        "users":1
    }
}
```

]

By the above query I can display all the users, But I want to display the size of the users set(array) only. Could anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) in mongo like following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate[{
    "$unwind": "$a"
    }, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$a.acid",
        "sessions": {
            $sum: 1
        },
        "users": {
            $addToSet: "$cid"
        }
    }
    }, {
    $project: {
        "sessions": 1,
        "users": 1,
        "size": {
            $size: "$users"
        }
    }
    }
])
```

**EDIT AFTER OP's comment that it gives invalid operator error-**

You can do something like again unwind `users` array and `count` number of users. But this involves again unwinding array so **not recommended**, The query will be something like following **(Not tested)**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$a"
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$a.acid",
    "sessions": {
        $sum: 1
    },
    "users": {
        $addToSet: "$cid"
    }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$users"
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "count": {
        $sum: 1
    },
    "sessions": {$push:"$sessions"},// u can use "sessions":{$first:"$sessions"} also.
    "users": {
        $push: "$users"
    }
    }
}])
```

Comment: @user1920 If u have any question about answer, u should use comments instead of editing answer. Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vishwas

Comment: sure @Vishwas but some other guy suggested me to don't add copmments. From next time onwardsd I will add comments. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1920 You should either modify your question or add comments to answers.